# flutter add method was called on null using provider

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-provider

Hello I want to add some value to my list. I have already googled for solutions but I can't see any other solutions besides initializing the list which I did.

When I try to add an item to my **AutomaticDateList** class I get the error:

> The method 'add' was called on null.
> Receiver: null
> Tried calling: add(Instance of 'AutomaticDate')

Here is the class with the list in it.

```
class AutomaticDateList with ChangeNotifier {
List<AutomaticDate> items = [];  // here I inialize

AutomaticDateList({this.items});

void addToList(AutomaticDate automaticDate) {
items.add(automaticDate);
notifyListeners();
}

 List<AutomaticDate> get getItems => items;
}
```

This is the item I want to add to the list.

```
class AutomaticDate with ChangeNotifier {
String date;
String enterDate;
String leaveDate;
String place;

AutomaticDate({this.date, this.enterDate, this.leaveDate, this.place});
```

Here I call the method using the provider inside a page widget

```
void onGeofenceStatusChanged(Geofence geofence, GeofenceRadius geofenceRadius,
  GeofenceStatus geofenceStatus) {
geofenceController.sink.add(geofence);
AutomaticDate automaticDateData = AutomaticDate();

automaticDateData.place = geofence.id;
automaticDateData.date = DateFormat("dd-mm-yyyy").format(DateTime.now());
if (geofenceStatus == GeofenceStatus.ENTER) {
  widget.enterDate = DateFormat("HH:mm:ss").format(DateTime.now());
} else {
  automaticDateData.leaveDate =
      DateFormat("HH:mm:ss").format(DateTime.now());
  automaticDateData.enterDate = widget.enterDate;
  widget.list.add(automaticDateData);

  WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((timeStamp) {
    AutomaticDateList automaticDateList =
        Provider.of<AutomaticDateList>(context, listen: false);
    automaticDateList.items.add(automaticDateData); // Here I add the data and get error "add was called on null"
    print(automaticDateList.getItems); 
  });
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in the initialization:

```dart
List<AutomaticDate> items = [];  // here I inialize

AutomaticDateList({this.items});
```

You set a default value, but you are using the *"auto-assign"* sintax in the constructor, saying that items passing **in the parameters are going to be assigned in the items property** of the class.

You are instantiating the class using this code:

```dart
AutomaticDate automaticDateData = AutomaticDate();
```

So, you are passing "null" implicitly as parameter, then `items []` got replaced with `null` value.

Just change the code to:

```dart
List<AutomaticDate> item;

AutomaticDateList({this.items = []}); // Default value
```